# After update: Drupal 7.35 Internal server error 500

Tags: drupal, drush

After using `drush up` on my drupal installation to update from drupal version 7.34 to drupal 7.35, I get Internal Server Error 500.

I have moved away .htaccess file and move it back without any result.

I have uploaded /overwritten the files with the ones downloaded for 7.35 without any result.

I have deleted everything from my server except for sites/* and themes/* and re-uploaded without any result.

I am running out of ideas. Please help!

P.S. Other websites on the same server still work properly so the server itself is not causing the issue.

P.P.S. I have also updated Ctools - From Chaos tools 7.x-1.6 to 7.x-1.7 in the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case was not a .htaccess file error. Drush makes also backups when updating, and after the error I have copied back all the old overwritten files and I still got the error.

Drush messes some file write permissions so, the problem was actually fixed by changing the permissions for index.php from 664 to 644. (Grup write permission has to be off and for some reason drush changes that when updating).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.
This thread helped: https://www.drupal.org/node/416906
Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/416906#comment-2831140 by ralgh
"I had a "500 Internal Server Error" error on a Rackspace Cloud Site (Mosso). I had to uncomment "RewriteBase /" in the .htaccess file to fix."

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me as well, and it turns out it was a file/folder ownership problem, which drush does not account for. I ran 'drush up drupal' with the root user; however, the server was set up to need the specific user for that directory set to the owner. Running drush up with the root user had changed some key files/folders ownerships.

In my case, all owner/groups had been set to 'root', which caused the 500 error. In filezilla you can see the owner/group of each file/folder in the far right column. If these are set to root, you need to change them back to the correct owner -- I used ssh and did the following command on the drupal root folder for the site:

```
chown -R CORRECTUSER:CORRECTUSER DRUPALROOTFOLDER
```

Not sure if this is your issue, but hopefully it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I received an Internal Server Error as well after a Drush update.  Changing file permissions on the index.php file from 664 to 644 fixed my issue.

Comment: OP has already mentioned he has solved the issue doing the same